# throw error while exec Object.fabric.parseSVGDocument

Tags: fabricjs

Our project select fabricjs as the graph library, but some svg file can't dispaly in canvas:

[image: throw error while exec Object.fabric.parseSVGDocument]

Same error evan fabricjs.com/kitchensink.

The demo svg file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1FnHkYoJU_vBDHeKKPD5edPUNhaTD9dbp

Comment: Added as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `xlink:href="#path3997"` in svg but there is no id containing `path3997`. So it is giving you the error.